# Validation code for IDN (Domain) with regex (regular expression)

Tags: regex

I want to check domains with regex. My old code was:

```
/^([a-z0-9]+([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+)?.){0,}([a-z0-9]+([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+)?){1,63}(.[a-z0-9]{2,7})+$/i
```

It is okey but this code doesn't validate IDNs (internationalized domain names) such as öü.com or öü.öü

**My domain format is:**

- example.com

**Besides, I don't want:**

- www.example.com
- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com

**Important note**: user can add the domains;

- with 2 extension like example.co.uk

Comment: for php http://goo.gl/uRpu0F

Comment: Most of examples use "[a-zA-Z0-9]" code like my code but this code doesn't support IDNs unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idn's such as `भारत.icom.museum` use [Punycode](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/Punycode.html) encoding, as defined in [RFC 3492](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3492.txt), before submission for DNS resolution.

It seems that you're using php, based on that, you should use the `idn_to_ascii()` function to convert the idn's, ex:

```
echo idn_to_ascii("भारत.icom.museum");
//xn--h2brj9c.icom.museum
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add support for IDNs by replacing `a-z` by `\pL`

Comment: Thanks, had a hard time finding a baked regex that allowed non-latin characters.